# Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error while trying to Request GET Service Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: integration, aws

I'm getting a SignatureDoesNotMatch error while trying to Request GET Service Amazon S3 bucket, with the following code:

```
String S3SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String S3BUCKET = 'XXXXX';
String S3KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String S3HOST = 's3.amazonaws.com';
String ENDPOINT = ('https://' + S3BUCKET + '.' + S3HOST + '/' + S3BUCKET);

String dateString =Datetime.now().formatGmt('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z');
String stringToSign = 'GET\n'                           
                            + '\n' 
                            + '\n'
                            + dateString + '\n' ;

Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA1', Blob.valueof(stringToSign),Blob.valueof(S3SECRET));
String signedString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);

HttpRequest con = new HttpRequest();

con.setHeader('Authorization','AWS ' + S3Key+ ':' + signedString);
con.setHeader('Host', S3BUCKET + '.' + S3HOST);
con.setHeader('Date', dateString);
con.setMethod('GET');
con.setEndPoint(ENDPOINT);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(con);


Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
String resBody = res.getBody();
System.debug(Logginglevel.WARN, 'GET STATUS CODE:' + statusCode + 'RES.GETBODY: ' + resBody + ' RES.GETSTATUS: ' + res.getStatus() + ' CON.GETENDPT: ' + con.getEndPoint());
```

Comment: Use 4-space indent to format code properly. This is a part of [Markdown.](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help)